# How to use SVG with kotlin-react

Tags: reactjs, kotlin

Hi could someone help me how use SVGs with Kotlin React.

I'd like to achieve similar thing as with following example using react and javascript:

```
const MyComponent = ({radius, color}) => (
  <svg width={radius * 2} height={radius * 2}>
    <circle cx={radius} cy={radius} r={radius} fill=  {color}/>
  </svg>
)
```

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find by myself any example or sufficient documentation.

Using Kotlin i don't know what language features I could use to achieve the same. Could anyone help me to fill following snippet using Kotlin?

```
fun RBuilder.MyComponent(radius: Int, color: String) {
  svg {
     ...
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

As of this writing Kotlin does not appear to have a library for svg similiar to kotlinx.html.
That being said, it is possible to create arbitrary xml in kotlin-react by reverse engineering the way kotlin-react and kotlinx.html interact. 
Or just use base react functions.

Method 1: Using kotlinx.html

```
import kotlinx.html.HTMLTag 
import react.*
import react.dom.*

// a custom tag builder, reuses the tag(...) function from kotlin-react and HTMLTag from kotlinx.html
inline fun RBuilder.custom(tagName: String, block: RDOMBuilder<HTMLTag>.() -> Unit): ReactElement = tag(block) {
    HTMLTag(tagName, it, mapOf(), null, true, false) // I dont know yet what the last 3 params mean... to lazy to look it up
}

// example use
inline fun RBuilder.mySVG(animTime: Double) {
    svg() {
        attrs["width"] = "800"
        attrs["height"] = "600"
        attrs["viewBox"] = "0 0 800 600"

        custom("circle") {
            attrs["cx"] = 150
            attrs["cy"] = 150
            attrs["r"] = 50.0 + sin(animTime) * 50.0
            attrs["style"] = object {
                val stroke = "black"
                val fill = "red"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Method 2: Using `child` and `createElement` from react.dom

```
open class CircleProps (
    val cx: Int,
    val cy: Int,
    val r: Int,
    val stroke: String,
    val fill: String,
    val strokeWidth: Int
    ): RProps {
}

inline fun RBuilder.mySVG2(animTime: Double) {
svg() {
    attrs["width"] = "800"
    attrs["height"] = "600"
    attrs["viewBox"] = "0 0 800 600"

    child(createElement("circle", CircleProps(150,150, 50.0 + sin(animTime) * 50.0, "black", "blue", 3)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to write SVG inline in the Kotlin/React file, however, JetBrain's own example shows [how to load an external SVG file in Kotlin-React](https://github.com/JetBrains/create-react-kotlin-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/src/logo/Logo.kt).

```
@JsModule("src/logo/react.svg")
external val reactLogo: dynamic
@JsModule("src/logo/kotlin.svg")
external val kotlinLogo: dynamic

fun RBuilder.logo(height: Int = 100) {
    div("Logo") {
        attrs.jsStyle.height = height
        img(alt = "React logo.logo", src = reactLogo, classes = "Logo-react") {}
        img(alt = "Kotlin logo.logo", src = kotlinLogo, classes = "Logo-kotlin") {}
    }
}
```

If you do work out how to do it inline, please post that solution back here for the community, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All SVG components already declared in `react.dom.svg.ReactSVG` object

`circle` missed right now - [I will add it](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/issues/1022) (fast WA in issue)

[`path` example](https://github.com/karakum-team/mui-kotlin/blob/6f1ad6b633e901e97095dd7a0a8b9ce8194eaf53/local-server/src/main/kotlin/App.kt#L16)

Answer (score 1):

You can also inline SVG files' contents directly into HTML.

1. Add `implementation(devNpm("@svgr/webpack", "6.2.1"))` into your `dependencies { ... }` inside **build.gradle[.kts]**.
2. Configure webpack to make reading and minifying of SVG files possible - create any JS file inside the **webpack.config.d** folder in your project's root with the following contents:

```js
config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.svg$/,
    use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
});
```

3. This step can be treated as optional - just a kind of syntax sugar. In your Kotlin sources create the following interface:

```kotlin
external interface SvgFile {

    @JsName("default")
    operator fun invoke(): ReactNode

}
```

4. Each time you want to inline some SVG into your HTML, include the required SVG file first (**arrow-right-thin.svg** is located at **src/main/resources/icons/arrow-right-thin.svg**):

```kotlin
@JsModule("./icons/arrow-right-thin.svg")
@JsNonModule
private external val arrowRightThin: SvgFile
```

and place it where needed in the component:

```kotlin
val example = fc<Props> { 
    +arrowRightThin()
}
```

Tested with:

- Kotlin JS plugin **1.6.10**
- React wrappers **18.0.0-pre.325-kotlin-1.6.10**

**Update (May 14, 2022)**: I think the interface described in #3 above should be changed into:

```kotlin
external interface SvgFile {

    @JsName("default")
    val component: ElementType<PropsWithClassName>

}

operator fun SvgFile.invoke(): ReactNode = component.create()
```

In this way in addition to the usage described in #4 above it also becomes possible to extend an included SVG by applying CSS classes to it:

```kotlin
val example = fc<Props> { 
    arrowRightThin.component {
        attrs.className = ClassName("some-class")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware some answers are outdated. As of 2022 Kotlin React wrappers include support for SVG.

Comment: Well, how would you add i.e. an `SVG` that is already defined somewhere, lets say `static/foo.svg`?